# Convert number to reversed array of digits

Tags: c#, arrays, long-integer

So I'm trying to convert a long to a reversed long array. This is what I have:

```
public static long[] Digitize(long n)
{
  string numConvert = n.ToString();

  char[] charArray = numConvert.ToCharArray();
  long[] charToLong = new long[charArray.Length]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    charToLong[i] = Convert.ToInt64(charArray[i]);

  return Array.Reverse(charToLong);
}
```

But every time I compile, I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type'void' to 'long[]'"
Just what am I not doing right here?

Comment: `.Reverse()` does *not* return a reversed array, it reverses the array inplace. You should call `Array.Reverse(charToLong);` and then `return charToLong;`

Comment: `long[] arr = 123L.ToString().Reverse().Select(x => (long)(x - '0')).ToArray();`

Comment: @RufusL `'0' == 48`

Comment: @L.B Mine was functionally the same as the OPs (returned the same results). But I deleted it, since it's not *really* functional

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.Reverse(charToLong);
return charToLong;
```

[Array.Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) returns void, not the reversed array. Click on the link and see the **Syntax**: `public static void` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the array, rather than the function.
`Array.Reverse()` doesn't return anything (`void`), so after calling `Array.Reverse(charToLong;)`, you need to return your array:

`return charToLong;`

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Reverse` on the string, then turn each character back to a `long` and return it.

```
public static long[] Digitize(long n)
{
    var reversed = n.ToString().Reverse().Select(x => long.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    return reversed;
}
```